# "Package Installation Error" when clicking "Install a New Package" under Packages (npm) in backend code, within Wix Corvid

Tags: npm, velo

When I try to click the ***Install a New Package*** button in the backend code menu in Wix this screen pops up
[image]

I don't know what to do as I'm trying to install a package and I can't even access the menu that you would traditionally use to do this. I've tried doing the same thing on a different website within wix and the menu opens as it would normally.

Does anyone know a fix or a way around this problem?